# Where can I find CSS theme for a Mobile web app for Android?

Tags: android, css, android-layout, cordova, trigger.io

I am developing a web mobile app for Android, and I'd be glad to use a native-theme like [this](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/multi-pane-layouts.html) one.

Android Play doesn't provide CSS of that theme, do you know where I could find it (or something similar)?

Edit: I just found [this](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/design/Android_Design_Fireworks_Stencil_20120229.png) png: [image: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/design/Android_Design_Fireworks_Stencil_20120229.png]
Does anyone created the CSS of this?

Comment: If you find a good one please let me know. I'm looking as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been looking for such css theme for sometime, as far as my search goes, I made a small list.

1. KendoUI Mobile - ( I think this is the best android theme ).
2. DojoMobile - Pretty good android theme.
3. QooxDoo Mobile - Good android theme.

I think the most close theme to what you want is KendoUI Mobile android theme. One thing about it, is that its paid.

Answer (score 1):

When looking for good themes for hybrid frameworks like Trigger.io Forge, it's best to look for mobile-ready HTML/CSS skeletons. The app itself is just a little web page so projects to assist with mobile web sites are most suitable.

Depending on what level you want to work at, you could take a look at Sencha Touch (we have a demo app built using with Trigger [here](https://github.com/trigger-corp/forge-template-sencha-touch)), [HTML5 Mobile Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile) and [320 and up](http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/); going from heavier to lighter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Mobile Showcase for qooxdoo's qx.Mobile:

http://demo.qooxdoo.org/devel/mobileshowcase-android/index.html#%2F

As you can see, it even supports tablet devices, now. The theming can easily changed via LESS/CSS.
But a lot of Android apps do not even have the native Android look. Simulating the native look is difficult, because the app can only have one appearance of a an android version (2.x, 3.x, or 4.x). So, I would not try copy it, because you do not know how Android 5.X and later will look like.